# Realizar funções dentro de um array, após determinado índice, e outra para os demais

Tags: javascript

Eu vou tentar ser breve na descrição. Eu tenho, por exemplo, dois arrays. Um deles, tem 6 índices e o outro 7.

Eu preciso pegar os 5 primeiros índices de cada array e realizar uma função, depois tenho que pegar os demais índices restantes desse array e realizar outra função. Se os demais índices restantes forem maior do que 5, eu tenho que pegar os 5 e depois os demais e assim sucessivamente.

As verificações, não tenho problema, mas estou com dificuldades em achar uma forma de encaixar as funções em cada um dos índices

Edit: 
Eu tentei algo mais ou menos assim:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if (i === 5) {
     // executa função para mod de 5
   } else if (i > 5) {
     if (i % 5 === 0) {
      // executa função para maiores do 5, que formam outro conjunto de 5
    } else {
      // executa função para maiores do 5, mas que não formam um novo conjunto de 5
    } 
 }
```

O problema, é que além desses inúmeros ifs, eu não achei um modo de, em cada função dentro dos ifs, utilizar somente os índices restantes para a função. Eu preciso chegar em um determinado índice, pausar, fazer a função, e ir até os próximos índices,fazer a verificação, e executar outras funções.

Para ilustrar melhor, na imagem eu tenho dois arrays, um do lado esquerdo com 6 índices, contendo os blocos e outro do lado direito, com 7 índices, contendo os blocos. A função tem que chamar primeiro os conjuntos de 5 blocos para ir pro chão, depois os conjuntos que não tem 5 indices restantes no array.

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Comment: Coloca o código que você tem até o momento, pra podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo do que eu tentei

Comment: Que genero de funções são essas que tem dentro dos `ifs` ? Se a execução é a cada `5`  basta utilizar `if (i !== 0 && i % 5 == 0)`. Ou pode até fazer o `for` até ao multiplo de `5` abaixo do tamanho e fazer o processamento restante fora do `for`.

Comment: Essas funções são de animação, usando tween. Pra tentar explicar, é um jogo de matemática, cada array é um conjunto de blocos. Então são dois conjuntos de bloco que são somados.

A resposta é escolhida deixando um espaço em branco no chão para os blocos. Os blocos então se encaixam no chão. Primeiro os conjuntos de 5, depois os demais. É difícil de entender falando assim, mas espero que tenha dado uma clareada rs

Comment: O problema é que se fizer só o for até o múltiplo de 5, os demais ficam sem função

Comment: Como eu faço para que a pergunta não fique como pendente?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi o que você quer. Você quer executar uma função nos indices 5, 10, 15 [...] de uma array, e nos outros indices executar outra função?

Comment: Não exatamente os indices 5, 10, 15... mas os índices até o 5, depois os índices até o 10, e quando os índices restantes não forem multiplos de 5, tipo, restarem apenas 3 indices, fazer outra função

Comment: Eu editei o post com uma imagem pra tentar clarear um pouco rs

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, primeiro você tem que realizar a função com TODOS os conjuntos de 5 que existirem, para somente depois fazer a função com os conjuntos menores que 5?

Comment: Isso, a ordem é primeiro os conjuntos de 5 se encaixando no chão, depois os menores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui abaixo segue a demonstração utilizando 1 array, para utilizar o segundo, é só copiar e alterar algumas variáveis.

Tentei explicar o código com comentários, qualquer dúvida não exite em pedir.

```
array1 = [];
array2 = [];
posFinalConjunto5Array1 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i<20; i++){ //ADICIONANDO ELEMENTOS NOS ARRAYS PARA DEMONSTRAÇÃO, IGNORAR NO SEU PROGRAMA
    array1.push(i);
    array2.push(i);
}
for(let contConjuntos5 = 1;contConjuntos5 <= (array1.length/5); contConjuntos5++){ //PERCORRE A QUANTIDADE DE CONJUNTOS DE 5 NO ARRAY 1
    i=(contConjuntos5*5)-5;
    while(i<5*contConjuntos5){
        // PERCORRE TODOS OS VALORES DE CADA CONJUNTO DE 5
        // executa função para mod de 5
        i++;
        if((array1.length-i)<5){
            posFinalConjunto5Array1 = i;
        }
    }
}
while (posFinalConjunto5Array1<array1.length){
    // PERCORRE VALORES RESTANTES
    // executa função para maiores do 5, mas que não formam um novo conjunto de 5
    posFinalConjunto5Array1++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Tava meio complicado achar uma saída